# Primefaces 5.0 Showcase is not running on JBoss EAP 6.2

Tags: primefaces, jboss6.x

I tried to deploy `Primefaces 5.0 Showcase` on `JBoss EAP 6.2` and failed.

**ERROR:**

`Unexpected HTTP response: 500`

```
Request
{
    "address" => [("deployment" => "primeshowcase_50.war")],
    "operation" => "deploy"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" =>     {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./primeshowcase_50" =>     "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service     jboss.web.deployment.default-host./primeshowcase_50:     org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: JBAS018040:     Failed to start context
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service:     JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}},
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Anyone ever encounter the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

Please check your libraries. I have been able to encounter the same problem. I fixed it by replacing the javax.faces-2.2.6.jar with javax.faces-2.1.17.jar.

Comment: Or unzip and remove it from the WEB-INF/lib and zip it again.  That worked for me too.